# Evaluate $\int^{\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{69}}{2}}}_{-\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{69}}{2}}}\sqrt{17-y^2}-y^2\,dy.$

Tags: calculus, integration

Can someone please explain to me how to take the following integral

$$\int^{\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{69}}{2}}}_{-\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{69}}{2}}}\sqrt{17-y^2}-y^2\,dy$$

I know how to take the integral of $y^2$ but not of sqrt $(17-y^2)$. I was thinking of u-sub but that doesn't really work. What are the steps invovled in taking the integral of $(17-y^2)$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and not a link to an image for equations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Firstly, what are your thoughts on the question? Which $u$ substitutions did you try? Secondly as @StephenG suggests, we prefer [$\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) so would much prefer to read that rather than have links to questions.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Use a trigonometric substitution, setting, say:
$$y=\sqrt{17}\sin t,\quad \mathrm d y= \sqrt{17}\cos t\,\mathrm d t. $$

Comment: Why do you set y=sin t. There is no sine anywhere in that integral. And doesn't the derivative of sin t just cos t?

Comment: @user493097 to get out of the square we substitute that then $ dy =cos(t) dt$

Comment: @user493097: I had mistyped the change of variable. Isham fixed it. The reason for such  substitution is to use known identities in order to remove the square  root. Here you end up in a $\sqrt{1-\sin^2t}=\sqrt{\cos^2t}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have 
\begin{equation}
\int \sqrt{17-y^2}-y^2\,dy=\int \sqrt{17-y^2}\,dy\,-\frac{y^3}{3} +C
\end{equation}
Let's now take care of the first integral. Like Bernard suggested, we will substitute $y=\sqrt{17}\sin(\theta)$ and $dy=\sqrt{17}\cos{\theta}\,d\theta$.
\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{17-y^2}\,dy&=\sqrt{17}\int \sqrt{17-17\sin^2(\theta)}\cos(\theta)\,d\theta \\
&=17\int \sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)}\cos(\theta)\,d\theta\\
&=17\int\cos^2(\theta)\,d\theta \\
&=17\left(\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{4}\right)\\
&=\frac{17}{2}\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{17}}\right)\right)+\frac{17}{4}\sin\left(2\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{17}}\right)\right)
\end{align}
Our final integral is then
\begin{equation}
\int \sqrt{17-y^2}-y^2\,dy =\frac{17}{2}\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{17}}\right)\right)+\frac{17}{4}\sin\left(2\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{17}}\right)\right)-\frac{y^3}{3}+C
\end{equation}
From here on, you can evaluate the definite integral.

Comment: Don't forget to add the condition $\;-\frac\pi2\le t\le\frac\pi2$.

Comment: I'm still confused. I'm just confused after you get 17 integral (cos thetha)^2 d(thetha). How do you get arc sin from that?

Comment: I solved for $\theta$ in terms of $y$ and substituted that expression instead of $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int^{\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{69}}{2}}}_{-\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{69}}{2}}}\sqrt{17-y^2}-y^2\,dy = $$
Let $$a = \sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{69}}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2(\sqrt{69}-1)} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sqrt{(\sqrt{69}-1)}$$ then 
$$\int^{a}_{-a}\sqrt{17-y^2}-y^2\,dy$$
$$\underbrace{\int^{a}_{-a}\sqrt{17-y^2}\,dy}_{I_1}-\underbrace{\int^{a}_{-a}y^2\,dy}_{I_2}$$

$$I_2 =\int^{a}_{-a}y^2\,dy = \mathop{\big|}\limits_{-a}^{a}\frac{y^3}{3} $$

$$I_1 = \int^{a}_{-a}\sqrt{17-y^2}\,dy = $$
 Apply trigonometric substitution
$$y=\sqrt{17}\sin\alpha,\quad dy=\sqrt{17}\cos{\alpha}\,d\alpha \quad\quad -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \alpha \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Also
$$\int^{a}_{-a} \sqrt{17}\cos \alpha\sqrt{17-17\sin ^2\alpha}\,d\alpha$$
$$\sqrt{17}\int^{a}_{-a} \cos \alpha\sqrt{17}\sqrt{1-\sin ^2\alpha}\,d\alpha$$
$$\sqrt{17}\int^{a}_{-a} \cos \alpha\sqrt{17}\cos\alpha\,d\alpha$$
$$\sqrt{17}\sqrt{17}\cdot \int^{a}_{-a} \cos ^2\left(u\right)\,d\alpha$$
$$17\cdot \int^{a}_{-a}\frac{1+\cos \left(2x\right)}{2}\,d\alpha$$
$$17\cdot \frac{1}{2}\int^{a}_{-a}1+\cos\left(2x\right)\,d\alpha$$
$$\frac{17}{2}\left(\int^{a}_{-a}1\,d\alpha +\int^{a}_{-a}\cos\left(2x\right)\,d\alpha\right)$$
$$\frac{17}{2}\left(\mathop{\big|}\limits_{-a}^{a}\alpha +\mathop{\big|}\limits_{-a}^{a}\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(2\alpha\right)\right)$$
Substitute back
$$\alpha=\arcsin \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{17}}\right)$$
$$I_1 = \frac{17}{2}\left[\mathop{\big|}\limits_{-a}^{a}\left(\arcsin \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{17}}\right)\right) +\mathop{\big|}\limits_{-a}^{a}\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(2\arcsin \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{17}}\right)\right)\right]$$

$$I_1 = \mathop{\big|}\limits_{-a}^{a}\left[\frac{17}{2}\arcsin \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{17}}\right) +\frac{17}{4}\sin \left(2\arcsin \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{17}}\right)\right)\right]$$

Also
\begin{align}\int^{a}_{-a}\sqrt{17-y^2}-y^2\,dy &= I_1 - I_2\\
&= \mathop{\big|}\limits_{-a}^{a}\underbrace{\left[\frac{17}{2}\arcsin \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{17}}\right) +\frac{17}{4}\sin \left(2\arcsin \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{17}}\right)\right)-\frac{y^3}{3}\right]}_{f(y)}\\
&=f(a) - f(-a)
\end{align}

$\text{Let } \frac{y}{\sqrt{17}} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{17}} = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sqrt{(\sqrt{69}-1)}}{\sqrt{17}} = \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{69}-1}{34}},\quad $
$\quad\frac{y^3}{3} = \frac{(a)^3}{3} = \frac{\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sqrt{(\sqrt{69}-1)}\right)^3}{3}  = \frac{\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{69}-1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{12}$

\begin{align}
f(a)&=\left[\frac{17}{2}\arcsin \left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{69}-1}{34}}\right) +\frac{17}{4}\sin \left(2\arcsin \left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{69}-1}{34}}\right)\right)-\frac{\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{69}-1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{12}\right]\\ 
&= 5.26101\dots 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
f(-a)&=\left[\frac{17}{2}\arcsin \left(-\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{69}-1}{34}}\right) +\frac{17}{4}\sin \left(2\arcsin \left(-\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{69}-1}{34}}\right)\right)+ \frac{\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{69}-1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{12}\right]\\ 
&= -5.26101\dots 
\end{align}

$$f(a) - f(-a) = 5.26101\dots - (-5.26101\dots ) = 10.52202\dots$$

> $$\int^{\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{69}}{2}}}_{-\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{69}}{2}}}\sqrt{17-y^2}-y^2\,dy = 10.52202\cdots$$